# Transforming mouse coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, scaling, graphic

Im making a graph program and im stuck at where I need to get mouse coordinates to equal graphic scale. With picturebox I use transform to scale my graphic:

```
RectangleF world = new RectangleF(wxmin, wymin, wwid, whgt);
        PointF[] device_points =
            {
                new PointF(0, PictureBox1.ClientSize.Height),
                new PointF(PictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, PictureBox1.ClientSize.Height),
                new PointF(0, 0),
            };
        Matrix transform = new Matrix(world, device_points);
        gr.Transform = transform;
```

[image]
Im using MouseMove function. Is there a way to transform mouse coordinates? When I put my mouse on x=9 I need my mouse coordinate to be 9.

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.X);
    }
```

Comment: Don't lose track of the *transform*.  You'll like its Invert() method, handy to map the mouse coordinates back to graph coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hans' comment implies, you can use a second `Matrix` to accomplish this. You can obtain it either by copying the original `Matrix` and calling the copy's `Invert()` method, or you can create the new `Matrix` from scratch by reversing your input rectangles from the original.

IMHO inverting is easier, but it does mean you'll need to create the inverse matrix and store it somewhere. E.g.:

```
    Matrix transform = new Matrix(world, device_points);
    gr.Transform = transform;
    inverseTransform = transform.Clone();
    inverseTransform.Invert();
```

where `inverseTransform` is a field in your class rather than a local variable, so that your mouse-handling code can use it later.

If you must construct the `Matrix` later, you could do it like this:

```
RectangleF device = new RectangleF(new Point(), PictureBox1.ClientSize);
PointF[] world_points =
    {
        new PointF(wxmin, wymin + whgt),
        new PointF(wxmin + wwid, wymin + whgt),
        new PointF(wxmin, wymin),
    };
Matrix inverseTransform = new Matrix(device, world_points);
```

In either case, you'd simply use the [`Matrix.TransformPoints()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yws7xa0(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your mouse-handling code to apply the inverse transform to the mouse coordinates to get back to your world coordinates.

Comment: I did this but it return the same X and Y values.

`inverseTransform = transform.Clone();
            inverseTransform.Invert();

            List<Point> location = new List<Point>();
            Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            location.Add(p);

            inverseTransform.TransformPoints(location.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("location = " + location[0]);`

Comment: Based on your comment here: The point values are transformed in-place. You created a new array to pass to the `TransformPoints()` method, but you pass it directly to the method instead of keeping a reference to it. So the method transforms the points, but you have no way to get the new values. Try `Point[] location = { new Point(e.X, e.Y) }; inverseTransform.TransformPoints(location);`.